# Connect models in Matlab Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape

Good day everyone!

I tried to make a circuit in matlab simulink, with an AC voltage, Resistor and Voltage measurement. AV voltage and Resistor connect quite well but voltage measurement can't connect the resistor connection.

how may I connect the voltage measurement to the resistor? Please help me thanks!

this is the circuit i want to simulate

[image]

I used different types of resistor, and Ac voltage but same results

Comment: With standard simulink you can't model resistors and voltage measurements. You have to be way more specific about the toolboxes you use and add a screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, your diode is from a different library (*Simscape\Foundation Library\Electrical*) than the voltage source, the resistance and the voltage measurement block (*Power Systems...*). Try to use blocks from the same Library.

See following picture for when I only use blocks from *Simscape\Foundation Library\Electrical*

[image]

[image: Configuration Parameters]

Comment: Did you tried to run it? because i copy your circuit and got this error:  "Each physical network must be connected to exactly one Solver Configuration block. There is no Solver Configuration block connected to Physical Network with the following blocks"

Comment: @Raldenors Yes, you need to connect a Solver Configuration block to each Simscape network. See http://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/solverconfiguration.html for more details.

Comment: sorry, but i can't find the "block parameters: solver configurations" where can i find that?

Comment: The "Solver Configuration" block is located in the "Simscape\Utilities" library. You can also search for the phrase "solver configuration" in the "Simulink Library Browser".

Comment: So i need to insert the Solver configuration in the simulink workspace and connect it to each model? like  AC Voltage -->solver configuration-->diode-->solver configuration-->resistor-->solver configuration-->voltage sensor?

Comment: please provide the whole circuit diagram including the solver configuration diagram. please! i badly need it thanks!

Comment: First of all, you have to decide whether you want to use "Simscape\Foundation Library" or "Simscape\Power Systems". For a "Simscape\Foundation Library"-based example, write e. g. "ssc_rc_circuit_sl" in the MATLAB command window. "Simscape\Power Systems"-based example write e. g. "power_1phPWM_IGBT" in the MATLAB command window.

Comment: Different Simscape libraries can be combined using appropriate sensors and actuators, because the flow and effort variables are different.